# example about fractor module of a finitely cogenerated module which is not finitely cogenerated?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

I am studing the book "Rings and Categories of modules" written by Frank W. Anderson and Kent R. Fuller. By definition posted below one can infer that a submodule of a f.c.o module is also f.c.o. However,what about a fractor module of f.c.o module?The answer seems negative but i can't find a example.Can someone give me some hint?

> **Finitely Cogenerated Modules**
> The definition of a finitely generated module has an obvious if not so familiar dual. A module $M$ is finitely cogenerated in case for every set $\mathscr{A}$ of submodules of $M$
> $$
> \cap A=0 \quad \text { implies } \quad \cap \mathscr{F}=0
> $$
> for some finite $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathscr{A}$. 
> For example, the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ is finitely generated but not finitely cogenerated. The group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\pi}}$ is finitely cogenerated but not finitely generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not hard to see that a module is Artinian iff every quotient is finitely cogenerated.

So in principle, it is obvious what to aim for: a finitely cogenerated module $M$ that isn't Artinian. There must be a strictly descending chain of submodules with nonzero intersection $N$, and then $M/N$ is not finitely cogenerated.

There exist rings (like [this one](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/54/)) which are finitely cogenerated as modules over themselves, but they have quotients which aren't Artinian. In the linked example above, the ring has a quotient isomorphic to $F[[x]]$ for a field $x$, which is a nonArtinian module over the ring. However, the ring itself is finitely cogenerated because its ideals are linearly ordered, and there is a smallest nonzero submodule.

Comment: Thank you very much.That's what I had been looking for.And the Link you give(that DaRT website) is useful.

Comment: @AlexHwang glad you like it!